# allow and deny parameters in collections

Tags: meteor

In the discover meteor book, the deny statement is used as follows:
https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/commit/chapter8-3

```
Posts.deny({
  update: function(userId, post, fieldNames) {
  .....
});
```

I don't understand how the update function is getting UserId, post, or even fieldnames since the edit form is doing the following:

```
var postProperties = {
            url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
            title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
        }

        Posts.update(currentPostId, {$set: postProperties}, function(error) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those parameters are given by Meteor. The signature for update functions on the client and in the `deny` object are different.

http://docs.meteor.com/#allow:

> `update(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier)`:
>
> > The user `userId` wants to
> >     update a document `doc`. (`doc` is the current version of the document
> >     from the database, without the proposed update.) Return `true` to permit
> >     the change.
> >
> > `fieldNames` is an array of the (top-level) fields in `doc` that the
> >     client wants to modify, for example `['name', 'score']`.
> >
> > `modifier` is the raw Mongo modifier that the client wants to execute;
> >     for example, `{$set: {'name.first': "Alice"}, $inc: {score: 1}}`.
> >
> > Only Mongo modifiers are supported (operations like `$set` and `$push`).
> >     If the user tries to replace the entire document rather than use
> >     $-modifiers, the request will be denied without checking the `allow`
> >     functions.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that these values are filled out for you by meteor. It understands who is making what modifications to which document and tells the server about it.

The client is calling `Posts.update` which sends a message to the server that `userId` is attempting to update a document (the contents of which are `post`), and the fields being updated are `fieldNames`. The server can then choose the accept the update based on those inputs.

This is documented [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#deny) and [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow).